# APK is not installing in S4 mini, Note Edge and Note 4

Tags: android, android-manifest

I have tested the application in Moto G, Moto X, Samsung S 5 and Nexus 7 and it was working fine. But when I tried to install the apk in S4 mini, Note Edge and Note 4, it is not working. My manifest file is as follows:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />

<!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />

<!-- Keeps the processor from sleeping when a message is received. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<!-- Creates a custom permission so only this app can receive its messages. -->
<permission
    android:name=".permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<permission
    android:name=".permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
```

Please suggest me a solution.

Comment: How are you attempting to install it? `adb install` ? What is the error message?

Comment: I copied the apk in the phone storage and then tried to install it. It is showing installing but I am not able to open the application.

Comment: what is minsdkVersion in your build.gradle file ?

Comment: <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The apk is in debug mode, in some devices the debug mode apk will not work and at the bigning only the app will crash, so build a signed apk then install the apk will work fine.